# How to properly install sklearn on Eclipse

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I recently came across a blog(http://stronginference.com/ScipySuperpack/) on how to install sklearn . I successfully installed it and it was stored on the path:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn

I then went to the properties of my eclipse; under the Interpreter-Python and added the path to the PYTHONPATH. I could import sklearn but when I ran this simple code to test everything:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
digits = datasets.load_digits()
print digits.data
```

It threw the following errors:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/licheng/Documents/workspaceII/SkLearnTutorial/Src/my_first_scilearn.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sklearn import datasets
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .base import load_diabetes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ..utils import check_random_state
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (/private/var/folders/fv/vhs3w0zn2q961_gyp8f2z_rw0000gn/T/pip-EVsI8B-build/sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

any help on what could be wrong? I have been on these for hours now.

Thanks

Comment: Does your numpy work fine? Is it compiled in 32 or 64-bit? Did you install scikit-learn in 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @pyan I think that was the problem. I re-installed it again using this command: pip install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn but will try again.

Comment: You may need to uninstall first in this case. Upgrade may not work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling NumPy, SciPy and scikit-learn.
Then reinstall those packages.

If you are using Windows, binaries for those packages have been provided by Christoph Gohlke, which can be quite convenient. Just download them and then use pip to install.

[Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)